# Compression or encrypt data

Tags: lossless-compression

I have two bytes and I want to compress them into a single byte using a key( key length can be up to 64 bits).
And further I want to be able to retrieve the two bytes by using the compressed byte and the same key.
Someone has an idea how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to compress any combination of 2 bytes down to a single byte?

Comment: @Phylogenesis: Now don't be too hasty dismissing this... it's actually possible :-)   Nobody said that the key must be random or freely chosen. 5 bytes (1 byte data and 4 bytes key) are sufficient to restore 2 bytes. Secret sharing algorithms to the rescue! This is actually an awesome "encryption", since without the information in the key, it's impossible to restore the information, no matter how much compute power you have.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2^{16} = 65,536 ways two choose a pair of 8-bit bytes.

However the result of your procedure is only one 8-bit byte, which can occur in 2^8 = 256 different variations.

So you could use this one byte as input to some decompressing procedure, but because there are only 256 different inputs, the procedure can not produce more than 256 different results,  so you can retrieve no more than 256 of the 65,536 possible pairs, the other pairs are not accessible, because you ran out of names for them, so to say.

This makes the procedure impractical, if more than 256 different input byte pairs occur.

(See the comments below for more details)

Compression would only be practical, if restrictions on your input data exist. E.g. if only the pairs p1 = (42,37) and p2 = (127,255) can occur as possible input you could compress them as 01 and and 02.

Comment: Technically speaking, general compression is impossible because lossless compression is a bijection on the natural numbers.

Comment: Indeed. So why are there lossless compressors available like zip, which seem to do a good job? Because they are not general, there are inputs to them which they can not reduce in size but might increase it. To cite Wikipedia: *Most lossless compression programs do two things in sequence: the first step generates a statistical model for the input data, and the second step uses this model to map input data to bit sequences in such a way that "probable" (e.g. frequently encountered) data will produce shorter output than "improbable" data.*